# Create mock up Active Directory Domain Service

Tags: security, active-directory-module

I am working on Sitecore intranet site using LDAP module to import, authenticate and manage the AD users, roles and profiles inside the Sitecore.

My question is that I need mock up Active directory in my local machine to start the implementation by connect to a dummy organization unit to return and update Active directory profiles.

Can anyone send me recommended AD domain service mock up or let me know if I can use different approach to work on LDAP from my local machine?

Comment: I explored the setting up AD on my local workstation a few years ago. You're in for a world of pain. I'm having trouble finding the link, but there were some issues with the fields that the AD module expects and what the local AD tool supported. If I find the link I'll update the comment.

Comment: I would just create a small Azure AD account and use that. Would be much simpler than trying to get AD running locally.